# Как в инспекторе Unity создать виджет с иконками?

Tags: c#, unity3d, виджет, unity3d-editor

Мне надо создать похожий, на кисть, виджет. В инспекторе Unity:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нашел исходники Unity [тут](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/tree/master/Modules/TerrainEditor/PaintTools) и [тут](https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled). Но пака не удалось найти код отвечающий за кисть на террейне. Может кто поделиться кодом или подскажет какой скрипт отвечает за виджет кисти?

Comment: С 90% вероятностью в исходниках используются internal части Unity, а значит `ctrl + c/ctrl + v` не сработает - проверено на собственном опыте. Лучше писать с нуля самостоятельно.

Comment: В принципе тут все примитивно, обычная плитка с текстурами, парочка колбеков и кнопка. Но кастомный редактор - дело такое, не уверен, что кто-то возьмется за ее реализацию. Может, есть какие-то конкретные вопросы?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Может, есть какие-то конкретные вопросы? -будут позже, пока только пробую